# TensorFlow: Read an Image Dataset from csv file

Tags: python, pandas, tensorflow

How can I create a `TensorFlow` image dataset from a `Pandas DataFrame` that contains image file paths and labels?

I have a `.csv` file from which I have loaded a `Pandas DataFrame`. The DataFrame has two columns: `img_path`, which contains the file paths to the images, and `label`.

I'm looking for a way to create a `TensorFlow` image dataset from this DataFrame, but I couldn't find any documentation or examples to help me achieve this. Can anyone provide guidance or code examples to get me started?

Answer (score 2):

To avoid to load all images in memory, you can use [`Sequence`](https://www.tensorflow.org/api_docs/python/tf/keras/utils/Sequence) to create your dataset and load data only when you process a batch.

*From an old project*:

```
class DataSequence(tf.keras.utils.Sequence):
    """
    Check documentation here: https://www.tensorflow.org/api_docs/python/tf/keras/utils/Sequence
    """

    def __init__(self, image_set, label_set, batch_size=32, image_size=(128, 128)):
        self.image_set = np.array(image_set)
        self.label_set = np.array(label_set)
        self.batch_size = batch_size
        self.image_size = image_size

    def __get_image(self, image):
        image = tf.keras.preprocessing.image.load_img(image, color_mode='rgb')
        image_arr = tf.keras.preprocessing.image.img_to_array(image)
        # additional simple image processing here (pad, crop, grayscale) if needed
        return image_arr

    def __get_data(self, images, labels):
        image_batch = np.asarray([self.__get_image(img) for img in images])
        label_batch = np.asarray(labels)
        return image_batch, label_batch

    def __getitem__(self, index):
        images = self.image_set[index * self.batch_size:(index + 1) * self.batch_size]
        labels = self.label_set[index * self.batch_size:(index + 1) * self.batch_size]
        images, labels = self.__get_data(images, labels)
        return images, labels

    def __len__(self):
        return len(self.image_set) // self.batch_size + (len(self.image_set) % self.batch_size > 0)
```

Usage:

```
import tensorflow as tf
import pandas as pd
import numpy as np
from sklearn.model_selection import train_test_split

INPUT_SHAPE = (256, 256, 3)
BATCH_SIZE = 32

df = pd.read_csv('dataset.csv')

# You can also use pd.factorize
class_to_label = dict(enumerate(np.unique(df['label'])))
label_to_class = {v: k for k, v in class_to_label.items()}

X = df['img_path']  # use path here and not data
y = df['label'].map(label_to_class)  # cast to numeric

# Split your data into 3 parts
X_train, X_test, y_train, y_test = \
    train_test_split(X, y, test_size=0.2, stratify=y, random_state=2023)
X_train, X_valid, y_train, y_valid = \
    train_test_split(X_train, y_train, test_size=0.2, stratify=y_train, random_state=2023)

# Create 3 datasets (train, valid and test)
train_ds = DataSequence(X_train, y_train, image_size=INPUT_SHAPE[:2], batch_size=BATCH_SIZE)
valid_ds = DataSequence(X_valid, y_valid, image_size=INPUT_SHAPE[:2], batch_size=BATCH_SIZE)
test_ds = DataSequence(X_test, y_test, image_size=INPUT_SHAPE[:2], batch_size=BATCH_SIZE)

# Build and compile your model
...

# Train your model
history = model.fit(train_ds, validation_data=valid_ds, epochs=10)

# Evaluate your model
loss, accuracy = model.evaluate(test_ds)
```

It should be enough to convert your dataframe as 3 datasets.

Other information (from my dataset):

```
# Get the first batch (data)
>>> train_ds[0][0].shape
(32, 256, 256, 3)  # BATCH_SIZE, HEIGHT, WIDTH, CHANNELS

# Get the first batch (label)
>>> train_ds[0][1].shape
(32,)  # BATCH_SIZE

# Get the first image of the first batch (numpy array)
>>> train_ds[0][0][0].shape
(256, 256, 3)  # HEIGHT, WIDTH, CHANNELS
```

Comment: @Simone. Does it solve your problem?